I encountered a strange problem while using Scanner in java. Its displays the phrase twice
Code
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sortirovka {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] massiv = new int[10];
        Scanner cons = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(cons.hasNextInt()){
                massiv[i] = cons.nextInt();
            }else {
                while(!(cons.hasNextInt())){

                    System.out.println("It's not an int, please input an int");
                    cons.nextLine();

                }
                massiv[i] = cons.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(massiv[i]);
        }
    }
}

Output if I am tryting to write not an int.
1
2
3
f
It's not an integer, please input an integer
It's not an integer, please input an integer
4
5

I don't need phrase "It's not an integer, please input an integer" twice. What's wrong with my code?

Scanner uses different algorithms to read lines and tokens... use next() instead of nextLine() to ignore a token
